# How to call WebAPI from a MVC Controller in a different project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have to create a Web API for my existing MVC project and make API Controllers calling the Service Layer and Models, which is contained in separate projects but in the same Solution, then create and map to DTOs.

[Layout of my Projects Solution in VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TtGJ5.png)
( ignore the **BookService.cs**. I was just trying to do a WebAPI tutorial and I put it in the same solution temporarily).

I have been reading up on WebAPI and how it functions for the past 2 days, but I am not being able to fully grasp an understanding on how to create a API Controllers for my MVC project without referencing it? I also have to make Views at the end, in my main project calling the uri, but I am very confused at this point.

It would help me out a lot if someone can please clarify how I am to tackle this or point me to a tutorial or some sort of source to learn the process of working with Web API. Thank you.

Comment: Is adding the Web API in a different project a requirement? Or can you add Web API controllers in your MVC project?

Comment: Yes, it is a requirement for me to make the Web API in a separate project, but in the same solution of the MVC project.

Comment: Calling the Web API end point from your MVC Controller seems wrong. Why can't the service be utilized by both projects?

Comment: You just make MVC project and API project separately. They don't need to reference each other.

Comment: @MacakM How am I supposed to make the call from my MVC project to the API? That's my main issue right now. I can't seem to find a source to learn on how to do it.

Comment: Why is it necessary? You typically need to call different API, not yours, that's why there are not any sources to this.

Comment: Your API shouldn't be handling a ton of logic, anyway. That should be in the service layer or some other layer. Calling the API from your MVC controller is just backwards.

Comment: @MarkC. I apologize, I didn't understand your question. From my understanding so far,  we have to make the API reference the Service and Models to make the Controllers. And then make the call from the MVC project to the API to create the Views.

Comment: I think there's a knowledge gap here. `Make the call from the MVC project to the API to create the Views` - this just doesn't make sense

Comment: Perhaps, there is a knowledge gap. That's how I was given an explanation or may be I misunderstood. I know I have to make API `Views` in my MVC project `ContosoUniversity`.  But I don't know how I can do that without referencing each other.

Comment: You should use HttpClient class to make service call from MVC project. I have done this in one of my previous project. Use [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/calling-web-api-using-httpclient/)

Comment: @MarkC. There's a perfectly good rationale for this design decision. It's call componentization. By breaking off functionality into separate components, you can deploy new versions of those components separately, without affecting other components like the MVC site. Doing it the way you suggest requires posting a new version of the MVC site any time the service-layer changes.

Comment: Microsoft is actually pushing this approach heavily now, especially given the cross-platform nature of Core, support for docker instances, and of course, their pet project, Azure.

Comment: I found something on Enabling Cross-origin Requests [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api). Reading on it to see if this might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

The Web Api project will be a separate "website", that you will need to host individually. Your MVC project will make requests to the Web Api using `HttpClient`.

Since the Web Api will be separate, you won't be able to utilize helpers like `Url.RouteUrl`, etc. to get URLs for the Web Api actions. You will also just need to *know* the full URI to the Web Api, including it's domain. There will be no way to programmatically ascertain this information, so I would recommend making use of Application Settings to avoid hardcoding in your MVC project.

Right-click on your MVC project in the Solution Explorer and choose Properties. Then click over to the Settings tab. Here, you can add strongly-typed settings that your MVC application can utilize. Importantly, these settings are still persisted in the Web.config, so you can change them using config transforms. Your Web Api will likely have different URLs depending on whether you're in development vs. production, for example, so that will make it very easy to ensure that you're hitting the right thing in the right environment.

You can add a setting like `WebApiUri`, and give it a type of `System.Uri`. Then, set it to the string value of where your Web Api is hosted in *development*, i.e. `http://localhost:12345`. It's important that the setting be specific to your development environment, as config transforms are not applied in development. For staging, production, etc. you'll change this setting appropriately in the applicable config transform, and it will be updated to the right value for the right environment when you publish.

Then, when you need to work with it, you'll just do something like:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = Properties.Settings.Default.WebApiUri;
```

Then, just make requests as normal through the client. For more information on working with `HttpClient`, see [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client).